# How to get a question reopened after it has been rephrased?

Tags: support

I would like to ask the high brow folks to take a look at a question that was closed.  I have rephrased it, added some arguments and flagged it, but it hasn't been evaluated so far.  What else should I do to apply for re-opening ?  Any suggestions about changing something or adding something else ?  The link is:  [Can your use of Latin-derived words indicate your social class?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160691/can-your-use-of-latin-derived-words-indicate-your-social-class)

Comment: Hi Luis, glad you made it to Meta! Just so you know, usually moderators don't re-open questions. High rep community members do this by voting to re-open. Also, you might give a short explanation of what you did to improve your question and/or solicit advice on how to improve the question further if the community feels it is still not ready to re-open.